# Ignoring whitespace in Javascript regular expression patterns?

Tags: javascript, regex, whitespace

From my research it looks like Javascript's regular expressions don't have any built-in equivalent to Perl's /x modifier, or .NET's RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace modifier.  These are very useful as they can make a complex regex much easier to read.  Firstly, have I missed something and is there a Javascript built-in equivalent to these?  Secondly, if there isn't, does anyone know of a good jQuery plugin that will implement this functionality?  It's a shame to have to compress my complex regex into one line because of Javascript's apparent regex limitations.

Comment: Why use jQuery? jQuery isn't the only way to import external code.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to add white space that isn't part of the regexp?
As far as I know it isn't possible with literal regexp.

Example:

```
var a = /^[\d]+$/
```

You can break up the regexp in several lines like this:

```
var a = RegExp(
  "^" +
  "[\\d]+" +  // This is a comment
  "$" 
);
```

Notice that since it is now a normal string, you have to escape \ with \\

Or if you have a complex one:

```
var digit_8 = "[0-9]{8}";
var alpha_4 = "[A-Za-z]{4}";
var a = RegExp(
    digit_8 +
    alpha_4 + // Optional comment
    digit_8
 );
```

Update: Using a temporary array to concatenate the regular expression:

```
var digit_8 = "[0-9]{8}";
var alpha_4 = "[A-Za-z]{4}";
var a = RegExp([
    digit_8,
    alpha_4, // Optional comment
    digit_8,
    "[0-9A-F]" // Another comment to a string
 ].join(""));
```

Comment: Yeah, but it's not the same.  You've got the ugly extra Javascript string concatenation syntax, and you still can't put Perl-style comments at the end of lines, like: h(a|o)t # <-- matches hat or hot

Comment: @Jez: But you can put JavaScript comments there. There is no other way, unfortunately. JS doesn't support verbose regexes.

Comment: @Jez:The end result is the same, but I agree that it's uglier. You can however put comments after each line with //, or you could put the different parts of the regexp into strings with meaningful names.

Comment: Tim, I don't quite understand what you mean about putting JavaScript comments there.  Could you post an answer giving an illustration?

Comment: @Jez: I added a comment to clarify.

Comment: OK some, this seems to be the best format possible given Javascript's lack of verbose regexes.  Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

Unfortunately there isn't such option in ES5, and I suspect it's unlikely to ever be in `RegExp` literals, because they're already very hard to parse and line breaks would make them even more ambiguous.

If you want easy escaping and syntax highlighting of `RegExp` literals, you can join them by taking advantage of the `source` property. It's not perfect, but IMHO less bad than falling all the way back to strings:

```
new RegExp(
    /foo/.source +
    /[\d+]/.source +
    /bar/.source
);
```

In ES6 you can create your own template string:

```
regexp`
  foo
  [\d+]
  bar
`;

function regexp(parts) {
   // I'm ignoring support for ${} placeholders for brevity,
   // but full implementation should escape them.

   // Note that `.raw` allows use of \d instead of \\d.
   return new RegExp(parts.raw.join('').replace(/\s+/g,''));
}
```