# JavaScript: Regex - Cannot start/end with punctuation, no repeating punctuation

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to create a Regex. The rules are:

1) Only letters (both upper and lower), numbers, periods (.) and underscores (_)

2) Must begin and end with letter or number (i.e. no periods/underscores)

3) Cannot have multiple punctuations in a row, of any kind (no .. or ._ or _. or __ or .._. etc)

4) Must contain at least 2 letters (either upper or lower or both, doesn't matter)

5) No less than 3 chars, no more than 25 chars

So far, what I have is:

```
^((?!.*[\._]{2})[A-Za-z0-9\._]{3,25})$
```

Which is close-ish. I've got rules 1, 3 and 5, but cannot figure out 2 and 4.

I thought that

```
(([A-Za-z0-9]?)([A-Za-z0-9\._]+)([A-Za-z0-9]?)){3,25}
```

would get rule 2, but it just breaks it.

I've been working on this for a couple hours, but none of the solutions I can find, or can come up with, are quite what I'm looking for.

An explanation of the Regex statement you provide would be greatly appreciated, but is not entirely necessary.

**EDIT 1**

As per noob's suggestion:

```
^((?!.*[\._]{2})(([\w\d\.]+)){3,25})$
```

**EDIT 2**

*Valid:*

```
1rockit.man
q3w
e4.45r.d.2
sp_am
```

(and anything else between 3 and 25 characters, without leading or repeating punctuation)

*Invalid:*

```
.ret.
123
12a
ret..wer
super_.duper
_petrat
petrat_
```

Comment: Use `shorthand` operators like `\w` and `\d`. Easier to comprehend. `\w` also include `_` so that's covered.

Comment: You might want to include a few **valid** and **invalid** matches for quick testing.

Comment: `1rockit.man` and `e4.45r.d.2` are **invalid** according to condition 2. _Cannot begin or end with non-letter/number_. You might wanna check again the given condition or the example.

Comment: @noob *cannot* begin with *non-letter* or *non-number*. i.e., *must* begin and end with either letter or number. I'll make it more clear in the post

Comment: Okay. `non-letter/number` seems to be confusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Building the regex from the rules (in an order of convenience):

- both upper and lower case => use case insensitive flag `//i`
- letters, numbers, underscore and period => `[\w.]*`
- 3-25 characters => `^[\w.]{3,25}$`
- cannot begin or end with period or underscore => `(?!^[\W_]|[W_]$)` 
   (notice uppercase `\W` meaning `not \w`)
- cannot contain 2 punctuation in a row => `(?![\W_]{2})`
- checking the negative lookahead in every position => `(?:(?!...)[\w.]){3,25}` 
   (using non-capturing group `(?:)` instead of `()` because we don't need to save the group)
- at least 2 letters => `(?:.*[a-z]){2}` assuming `i` flag
- wrap into lookahead (not consuming any characters) so we can check multiple conditions => `(?=(?:...))`

The final regex literal:

```
/^(?=(?:.*[a-z]){2})(?:(?!^[\W_]|[\W_]{2}|[\W_]$)[\w.]){3,25}$/i
```

https://regex101.com/r/yK1cB3/5#javascript

---

FTR: in languages that support the `x` flag (ignoring whitespace inside the regex), you could make it more readable (see a [workaround for javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3830762/1176601)):

```
^
(?=
  (?:.*[a-z]){2}
)
(?:
   (?!^[\W_]|[\W_]{2}|[\W_]$)
   [\w.]
){3,25}
$
```

Comment: How would I modify this to allow punctuation (just the periods and underscores) at the start and end? I tried changing the middle section to `(?:(?![\W_]{2}$)[\w.])`, which *does* allow beginning and ending punctuation, but it also allows multiple punctuation in a row.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. `/^(?=(?:.*[a-z]){2})(?:(?![\W_]{2})[\w.]){3,25}$/i`, for anyone else who might be wondering.

Answer (score 7):

Based upon your conditions I came up with following regex. It's only modification over your current regex.

**Regex:** `^(?=.*[A-Za-z].*[A-Za-z])([A-Za-z0-9]((?!.*[\._]{2})([\w\d\.]{1,23}))[A-Za-z0-9])$`

**Explanation:**

- The first part `(?=.*[A-Za-z].*[A-Za-z])` checks for whole string to have **`two`** characters separated by **anything** (that's pretty much the case here).
- I added checks on the beginning and end of string which should be either **letter** or **number**.
- Apart from that the length will also vary now as first and last character is counted rest of the length will be only **23 characters**.

<kbd>**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yK1cB3/3)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

You can try with:

```
^(?=.*[a-zA-Z].*[a-zA-Z].*)[a-zA-Z0-9](?!.*[._]{2,}|.*[._]$)[._a-zA-Z0-9]{2,24}$
```

or, if you prefer make it using character classes like *\w \d \s*, you could use:

```
^(?=.*[a-zA-Z].*[a-zA-Z].*)\w(?!.*[._]{2,}|.*[._]$)(\w|[._]){2,24}$
```

> http://regexr.com/3ct34

Answer (score 1):

Takin part in ur riddle challenge. Here's my version. Would have nice performance as well :)

```
/^(?=(?:.*?[a-z]){2})[a-z\d](?!.*?[._]{2})[\w.]{1,23}[a-z\d]$/i
```

`i` [flag](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) for caseless matching where `[a-z]` is equivalent with alpha `[a-zA-Z]`.
`\w` is a [short](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) for word character `[A-Za-z0-9_]` thus `[\w.]` will match allowed characters.
`(?:` opens a [non capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group) mostly used for repitition or alternation (if group not needed).
`(?=` `(?!` [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) are zero-length assertions triggered at a certain position.

- Rule 2: Require one alnum `[a-z\d]` at `^` start and one at `$` end
- Rule 1 & 5: No less than 3, no more than 25  with start/end substracted `[\w.]{1,23}`
- Rule 3: `(?!.*?[._]{2})` no consecutive punctuation checked by negative lookahead.
- Rule 4: `(?=(?:.*?[a-z]){2})` at least 2 letters checked with positive lookahead.

[Check out demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/sX5wS8/1)